# Should we Have New Tags for Question on The Path and The Fruit, Stages of Sainthood, and Fruit of Attainment?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we need tags for discussions about the Path and The Fruit and the stages of Sainthood and Fruit of Attainment. There is a tag for stream entry but not for the others.

Comment: Can you give examples? Once-returner and so on?

Comment: Magga, Phala, Magga-Phala, Non-Returner, Samapatti, etc.

Comment: Sounds good, go forth and ask questions and tag them as such!

Comment: Created the following for tag proposals so we can vote on good ones: http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/285/new-tag-proposal

Comment: Tags don't have an independent existence. Questions have tags. If you see a question which would benefit from the addition of one of those tags, then add it. You don't create the tags first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general principle of tagging is that people should just tag questions as makes sense to them. We can always retag if it doesn't make sense and I believe tags can always be removed entirely if some really bizzare ones crop up. I think the tags we have got at the moment all seem perfectly fair really. The good ones float to the top anyway.

I would just go forth and tag.

Comment: I has the problem of finding tags for questions relating to above topic. They not be that frequent but be beneficial if we have some tags.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala you can just create them yourself. Just type the new tag into the tag box when creating your question and it will be created. You have the power!!

Comment: I am a bit reluctant. Best discuss what is the best rendering / version of it before doing it.

Comment: Best is to have some consensus what they should be. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala sorry I'm not the expert here. I was hoping you were ;-)

Comment: Created the following for tag proposals so we can vote on good ones: http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/285/new-tag-proposal